# Interpreting a first order sentence

Tags: logic, relations, first-order-logic

I've been given this first order sentence with a binary relation symbol $R$:

$\forall x \exists y (R(x, y)  \land \forall z(R(x, z) \implies (R(y, z) \land (y=z)) ) $

We are then given two structures of this sentence and asked if the structure models the sentence:

1. $S$ has domain the natural numbers and $R = \{(u, v) : u < v\}$
2. $S$ has domain the rational numbers and $R = \{(u, v) : u < v\}$

As these are two separate questions, I would expect the answer to change.  But it appears that neither of these structures model the equation, as $R(y, z) \land (y=z)$ cannot be true for any z and y. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Maybe $R(y,z)\lor (y=z)$ was intended.

Comment: In the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers, the formula (with $\lor$) is satisfied interpreting $y$ as the *immediate successor* of $x$ (i.e. as $x+1$). In this case, every successor $z$ of $x$ either coincide with $y=x+1$ or is greater thatn $y$.

Comment: It's definitely $\land $ in the paper I was using. Maybe there was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the formula tries to express the existence of a supreme and it's unicity (hence the $y=z$ consequent). Since that kind of number does not exist neither in $\mathbb{N}$ nor in $\mathbb{Q}$, then you can be sure that neither $S_1$ nor $S_2$ model the formula.